# Get Firebase child value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to only get a specific child value from Firebase using JavaScript.
I always get the entire child values.

This is what it looks like:

```
Child a -
        |- fcmToken: 'abcdefg'

Child a -
        |- fcmToken: 'hijklmn'
```

I always get the entire thing. `"Child a – fcmToken: 'abcdefg'"`
But I only want to get the fcmToken value `'abcdefg'` and `'hijklmn'`

Ho can I do so?

I tried this:

```
return admin.database().ref('/fcmToken').once('value', snapshot => {

var uid = snapshot.val();

return admin.database().ref('/fcmToken/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

  var fcmToken = snapshot.val();
  console.log('FCMTOKEN:', fcmToken)

});
```

But it's not working. Any ideas, how I can only get the desired values `'abcdefg'` and `'hijklmn'`

Comment: Your DB structure shows `"Child a – fcmToken: 'abcdefg'"` but where is `Child a` in `ref()` ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj "Child a" would be the "uid" in the `ref('/fcmToken/' + uid)`

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying I have finally found a solution!
Here is what I did:

```
return admin.database().ref('/fcmToken').once('child_added', snapshot => {

var uid = snapshot.key;

return admin.database().ref('/fcmToken/' + uid + '/fcmToken').once('value', snapshot => {

  var fcmToken = snapshot.val();

});
```

The `var fcmToken = snapshot.val();` was the data, I needed and was trying to get.